# meteor event handler suppression issue

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here is my button click handler:

```
Template.kanjifinder.events({
  'click input.btnOK': function () {
    console.log("click");
        SetCharacters();
      }
});
```

But after I add the event handler below for my text input the above button click code has stopped working.

```
Template.kanjifinder.events = ({
'keydown input.txtQuery': function (evt) {
  if (evt.which === 13) {
     SetCharacters();
  }
 }
});
```

How can I get both the keydown event handler and the button click event handler working?

Comment: Basically, you're replacing Template.kanjifinder.events in the second code block.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `=`

```
Template.kanjifinder.events({
'keydown input.txtQuery': function (evt) {
  if (evt.which === 13) {
     SetCharacters();
  }
 }
});
```

Also you can use both together in one:

```
Template.kanjifinder.events({
    'click input.btnOK': function () {
        console.log("click");
        SetCharacters();
    },
    'keydown input.txtQuery': function (evt) {
        if (evt.which === 13) {
            SetCharacters();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: oh lord! how did I miss that `=` *facepalm*
Thanks again @Akshat!